# How to create grid fluid responsive consist of three boxes?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I am tired for create responsive grid in css & html,the following image may be easy to figure out. many thanks for help.

Here is my example image:

[image]

Comment: where is the html and css code? what is going in the boxes? text or images?

Comment: yeap, please provide some more details, don't just throw an image and expect a solution

Comment: I want to putting images instead of Box1,Box2,Box3 and Box4. you can create that is layout thanks dear David Thomas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Here's how Stack Overflow works: learn, try, fail, then come ask for help here. So you need to show some effort yourself.

2) Anyway, there must be a million ways to build such a layout. Here is a sample with Bootstrap, using images as content. Includes some unfortunate stabbing of the framework, to get rid of the gutter between things.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/csy1wypc/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="single">
        <div class="img-holder">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/900/400/">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="double">
            <div class="img-holder">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/800/400/">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="single">
            <div class="img-holder">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/600/400/">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="single">
            <div class="img-holder">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/700/400/">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-6,
.col-md-12,
.col-sm-6,
.col-sm-12,
.col-xs-6,
.col-xs-12 {
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  margin: 0;
}

.single,
.double {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.single {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.double {
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.single .img-holder,
.double .img-holder {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.single img,
.double img {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -200%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help dear Roope.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an excellent framework for it : bootstrap !

They have an excellent grid system :)

You might find everything you need here :

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Hope that should help :)

Comment: Yes I know but is custom design, you right Bootstrap is cool.

Comment: You're aware that Bootstrap is just a framework right? You can still create custom designs using it.  Doing it to learn is great, but if you're doing it because you have some misconception about what Bootstrap is you're just reinventing the wheel for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my css & Html but I can't write prefect css I am so beginner with css & html.

```
<div class="wrapper">


        <div class="Box1">

            Box1

        </div>


        <div class="container_right">


            <div class="Box2">Box2</div>


            <div class="Box3">Box 3</div>


            <div class="Box4"> Box4</div>


        </div>



    </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .wrapper { 
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 1060px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:5px;
}

  .wrapper Box1 {
      float:left;
      margin-right:10px;
      width:520px;
      padding:5px;
      background-color:#808080;
  }

  .wrapper .container_right {
      width:520px;
      float:right;
  }

  .container_right .box2 {
      width:100%;
      height:200px;
      margin:5px;
      padding:5px;
      background-color:#808080;
  }

 .container_right .box3 {
     width:50%;
     height:200px;
     padding:5px;
     background-color:#808080;

 }

 .container_right .box4 {
     width:50%;
     height:200px;
     padding:5px;
     background-color:#808080;
 }
```